# EF Code First - Object coming from database is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent-interface

I am having some issues when trying to get objects out of the database with EF Code First. The program that I'm using is Visual Studio 2010 and the type of project is a ASP.NET MVC3 project.

Now, the issue is that an associated object is always null, though the FK is properly configured in the database.

Concrete scenario: a User has a Team (optional) and a Team has its Users (Users.Count can be zero).
Now when logged on to the webapp with a certain user, it should be possible to display the other users in that team. The problem is that the Team object of the logged on user is null. I've found a workaround using a foreign key in the User (int? teamId) and allocating the proper team using this foreign key. However my problem should be solved without using this method. My code:

```
public class Team
    {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> UsersInTeam { get; set; }

    public Team()
    {
        UsersInTeam = new List<User>();
    }

    public void AddUser(User user)
    {
        if(UsersInTeam.Contains(user))
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Cannot add {0} to {1} because the user is already assigned to that team", user.Name, Name));

        user.Team = this;
        UsersInTeam.Add(user);
    }

 public class User
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdminstrator { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Team = new Team();
    }
}
```

Now for the mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasMany(t => t.UsersInTeam).WithOptional(u => u.Team).Map(m => m.MapKey("TeamId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(u => u.Team).WithMany(u => u.UsersInTeam).Map(m => m.MapKey("TeamId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

So after logged in I have a User object with all the proper attributes coming from the DB, except user.Team is null. In the database the User table has a foreign key colum TeamId as it should and the users have the corresponding teamId, still Team is always null.

I would really appreciate it if someone could take a look at it, because I'm getting pretty frustrated because of this issue.

Greetings

Comment: You can always retrive it by querying the user table for all entries that have the same teanId as the logged in user

Comment: Yes that is true. That would be the case if I only needed the users from that team. In my case I need the Team object because it also has associations with other objects that will be used further on in the app.

Comment: Try add a TeamId property on class User. I always do that, and I havn't seen such things happen.

Answer (score 1):

In your query include the team by

```
Users.Include(e => e.Team)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `.Include` you are doing *eager loading*. You can also do an *explicit load* by doing this after the query:

```
var User = context.Users.Find(id); // Load the User.
context.Entry(User)
    .Reference(u => u.Team)
    .Load();
```

And you can also:

```
var Team = context.Teams.Find(id);
context.Entry(Team)
    .Collection(t => t.Users)
    .Load();
```

Related entries loaded! :)